# In SQL Server, how to number matching sets of data in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the set of data shown below, I need to be able to derive the value in the `optionGroupNumber` on the right, based on the values in the `optionType` & `optionValue` columns. So, for Order 1, the options selected for detail keys 1 & 2 are the same (green shade), so they get `optionGroup` value 1. Detail key 3 (blue shade) has a different set of options than 1 & 2, so it gets 2 as its `optionGroupNumber`.

`Optionvalues` are arbitrarily entered by users so they can be anything.

How can this be done using T-SQL?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you need case/when.

Comment: If will be so much easier if you can include the expected outcome using the sample data included.

Comment: @DT - the expected outcome is what's in the last column, optionGroupNumber.

Comment: jump to `sqlfiddle.com` or `rextester.com` and muck up your data. this sounds like a job for superman

Comment: I don't understand. You want to `update` column `optionGroupNumber` based on the **color** of a cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement is tough to understand so I'll base my answer on this:

> Given the set of data shown below, I need to be able to derive the
>   value in the optionGroupNumber on the right, based on the values in
>   the optionType & optionValue columns.

Say we had a table with animals and colors and we wanted to create a group number based on animals that were the same type and color. We would do so using RANK() like this:

```
-- sample data
DECLARE @sometable TABLE (someId int identity, pet varchar(20), color varchar(20));
INSERT @sometable (pet, color)
VALUES ('cat','blue'),('pig','green'),('cat','yellow'),('pig','green'),('cat','yellow'),
('cat','blue'),('dog','black'),('dog','white'),('pig','green'),('dog','black');

-- group by pet and color
SELECT *, OptionGroupNumber = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY pet, color)
FROM @sometable;
```

Result:

```
someId      pet                  color                OptionGroupNumber
----------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
1           cat                  blue                 1
6           cat                  blue                 1
3           cat                  yellow               2
5           cat                  yellow               2
10          dog                  black                3
7           dog                  black                3
8           dog                  white                4
9           pig                  green                5
4           pig                  green                5
2           pig                  green                5
```

Note how the grouping works:

[image]

To update and existing column you would take this logic and apply it to an UPDATE statement like this:

```
-- sample data
DECLARE @sometable TABLE 
  (someId int identity, pet varchar(20), color varchar(20), OptionGroupNumber int);

INSERT @sometable (pet, color)
VALUES ('cat','blue'),('pig','green'),('cat','yellow'),('pig','green'),('cat','yellow'),
('cat','blue'),('dog','black'),('dog','white'),('pig','green'),('dog','black');

WITH generateOptionGroupNumber AS
(
  SELECT *, newOptionGroupNumber = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY pet, color)
  FROM @sometable
)
UPDATE generateOptionGroupNumber
SET OptionGroupNumber = newOptionGroupNumber

SELECT * 
FROM @sometable
ORDER BY OptionGroupNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query...

```
WITH cte (detailkey, alloptionvalues) 
     AS (SELECT detailkey, 
                allOptionValues = Stuff((SELECT N', ' + optionvalue 
                                         FROM   tablename AS subTbl 
                                         WHERE  subTbl.detailkey = mainTbl.detailkey 
                                         FOR xml path(N'')), 1, 2, N'') 
         FROM   tablename AS mainTbl 
         GROUP  BY detailkey) 

SELECT tablename.orderno, 
       tablename.detailkey, 
       tablename.style, 
       tablename.[format], 
       tablename.leather, 
       tablename.optiontype, 
       tablename.optionvalue, 
       tablename.optionadditionalinfo, 
       tmpQueryTbl.optionGroupNumber 
FROM   tablename 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT *, 
                          Dense_rank() OVER(ORDER BY alloptionvalues) AS optionGroupNumber 
                   FROM   cte) tmpQueryTbl 
               ON tablename.detailkey = tmpQueryTbl.detailkey
```

Result

```
+---------+-----------+-------+--------+---------+-----------------------------------+-------------+----------------------+-------------------+
| orderno | detailkey | style | format | leather |            optiontype             | optionvalue | optionadditionalinfo | optionGroupNumber |
+---------+-----------+-------+--------+---------+-----------------------------------+-------------+----------------------+-------------------+
|       1 |         1 | WJ7   | MRBL   | PYT     | ADDITIONAL STAMPING               | BLIND       | NULL                 |                 1 |
|       1 |         1 | WJ7   | MRBL   | PYT     | ADDITIONAL STAMPING FOIL          | BLIND       | NULL                 |                 1 |
|       1 |         1 | WJ7   | MRBL   | PYT     | ADDITIONAL STAMPING FOIL POSITION | BLC         | NULL                 |                 1 |
|       1 |         1 | WJ7   | MRBL   | PYT     | ETA FOR MATERIALS                 | 4/25/2018   | NULL                 |                 1 |
|       1 |         2 | WJ7   | MRBL   | PYT     | ADDITIONAL STAMPING               | BLIND       | NULL                 |                 1 |
|       1 |         2 | WJ7   | MRBL   | PYT     | ADDITIONAL STAMPING FOIL          | BLIND       | NULL                 |                 1 |
|       1 |         2 | WJ7   | MRBL   | PYT     | ADDITIONAL STAMPING FOIL POSITION | BLC         | NULL                 |                 1 |
|       1 |         2 | WJ7   | MRBL   | PYT     | ETA FOR MATERIALS                 | 4/25/2018   | NULL                 |                 1 |
|       1 |         3 | WJ7   | MRBL   | PYT     | ADDITIONAL STAMPING               | SILVER      | NULL                 |                 2 |
|       1 |         3 | WJ7   | MRBL   | PYT     | ADDITIONAL STAMPING FOIL          | SILVER      | NULL                 |                 2 |
|       1 |         3 | WJ7   | MRBL   | PYT     | ADDITIONAL STAMPING FOIL POSITION | FLR         | NULL                 |                 2 |
|       1 |         3 | WJ7   | MRBL   | PYT     | ETA FOR MATERIALS                 | 4/25/2018   | NULL                 |                 2 |
+---------+-----------+-------+--------+---------+-----------------------------------+-------------+----------------------+-------------------+
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0b419/1/0

To Update the data, use this SQL query

```
WITH cte (detailkey, alloptionvalues) 
     AS (SELECT detailkey, 
                allOptionValues = Stuff((SELECT N', ' + optionvalue 
                                         FROM   tablename AS subTbl 
                                         WHERE  subTbl.detailkey = mainTbl.detailkey 
                                         FOR xml path(N'')), 1, 2, N'') 
         FROM   tablename AS mainTbl 
         GROUP  BY detailkey) 

UPDATE tablename 
SET    tablename.optiongroupnumber = resultSet.optiongroupnumber 

FROM   (SELECT tablename.orderno, 
               tablename.detailkey, 
               tablename.style, 
               tablename.[format], 
               tablename.leather, 
               tablename.optiontype, 
               tablename.optionvalue, 
               tablename.optionadditionalinfo, 
               tmpQueryTbl.optiongroupnumber 
        FROM   tablename 
               INNER JOIN (SELECT *, 
                                  Dense_rank() 
                                    OVER( 
                                      ORDER BY alloptionvalues) AS 
                                  optionGroupNumber 
                           FROM   cte) tmpQueryTbl 
                       ON tablename.detailkey = tmpQueryTbl.detailkey) resultSet 
-- use where with PK columns  
WHERE  tablename.orderno = resultSet.orderno 
       AND tablename.detailkey = resultSet.detailkey 
       AND tablename.optiontype = resultSet.optiontype 
       AND tablename.optionvalue = resultSet.optionvalue 
       AND tablename.style = resultSet.style 
       AND tablename.[format] = resultSet.[format] 
       AND tablename.leather = resultSet.leather
```

Comment: If you don't understand the query, please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50031953/2

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how efficient this will be. It seems to work on a small amount of test data though.

```
with X as (
    select
        orderNo, detailKey, optionType, optionValue,
        count(*) over (partition by orderNo, detailKey) as optionCnt,
        dense_rank() over (partition by orderNo order by optionType, optionValue) as tag
    from O
), Y as (
    select
        coalesce(x1.orderNo, x2.orderNo) as orderNo,
        x1.detailKey as detailKey1, x2.detailKey as detailKey2,
        row_number() over (partition by coalesce(x1.orderNo, x2.orderNo) 
                           order by x1.detailKey, x2.detailKey) as rnk
    from X x1 full outer join X x2
        on x2.orderNo = x1.orderNo and x2.detailKey > x1.detailKey and x2.tag = x1.tag
    group by coalesce(x1.orderNo, x2.orderNo), x1.detailKey, x2.detailKey
    having count(x1.orderNo) = min(x1.optionCnt) and count(x2.orderNo) = min(x2.optionCnt)
), Z as (
    select orderNo, detailKey,
        coalesce('Merge with ' + cast(mergeKey as varchar(4)), 'Cannot merge') as note,
        dense_rank() over (partition by orderNo
                           order by coalesce(mergeKey, detailKey)) as optionGroupNumber
    from
        (select distinct orderNo, detailKey from O) o
        outer apply (
            select min(y.detailKey1) as mergeKey from Y y
            where y.orderNo = o.orderNo and o.detailKey in (y.detailKey1, y.detailKey2)
        ) as m
)
select * from Z;
```

Here's a quick overview:

1. Grab the count of options per `detailKey`. Number each pair of option settings.
2. Join up the sets of options to see if they match entirely.
3. Reduce sets of matches to a single, canonical representative.

http://rextester.com/GEUD41256